numpy 2d array into block matrix
Given a 2x6 array like below
x = np.array([[0,1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10,11]])

How do I convert this in to 6x6 matrix with block diagonal filled with above array
Input

output I am expecting

I got the below error while trying to post this.
Your post is mostly images. Add additional details to explain the problem and expected results.
Please ignore this last bit

Are you restricted from using scipy?

Using scipy.linalg.block_diag:
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import block_diag

x = np.array([[0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
              [6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]])
x_ = np.split(x, 
              indices_or_sections = 3,  # modify as needed
              axis = 1)  
out = block_diag(*x_)

out
Out[]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 6,  7,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  2,  3,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  8,  9,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  4,  5],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 10, 11]])

Depending on how you want to split up your original array, different permutations of np.split's indices_or_sections parameter will probably handle it the way you want.  In this case I used a naive assumption.

Thanks very much for the very readable and pythonic solution

I would use numpy indexing with numpy.indices and numpy.full:
x = np.array([[0,1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10,11]])

# get indices
N = x.shape[1]
X, Y = np.indices(x.shape)
shift = np.arange(N)//2*2

# initialize output with -1
# you can pick another value if desired
out = np.full((N, N), -1, dtype=x.dtype)

# assign original values
out[X+shift, Y] = x

Output:
array([[ 0,  1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
       [ 6,  7, -1, -1, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1,  2,  3, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1,  8,  9, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1,  4,  5],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1, 10, 11]])


Thanks very much for the answer. I assume this would be the fastest.
